# importing of data from Excel To Access database by c#.net

Tags: c#-4.0

I am working on a windows application in c#.net where I need to import an excel sheet into an Access database by the use of code in c#. I found the following code on the net and tried to use :

```
 string path = @"D:\project_excel"; 
      OleDbConnection con;
        System.Data.DataTable dt = null;
        //Connection string for oledb
        string conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + path + "; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
        con = new OleDbConnection(conn);
        try
        {
            con.Open();

            dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            String[] excelsheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
            int i = 0;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                excelsheets[i] = dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                i++;
            }
            // here i manaually give the sheet number in the string array
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            foreach (string temp in excelsheets)
            {
                // Query to get the data for the excel sheet 
                //temp is the sheet name
                string query = "select * from [" + temp + "]";
                OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
                adp.Fill(ds, temp);//fill the excel sheet data into a dataset ds
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

However it gives an exception which is mentioned below :

> The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file 'D:\project_excel'.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.

Further I don't know the meaning of Extended Properties. I am using Microsoft Office 2007 package.If I set Extended Properties = 7.0 it gives following error :

> Could not find installable ISAM.

Please help by providing some code sample.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is the file open in excel while you are running your code?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the connection string is correct for your Access database version.

For details Visit [ConnectionString.com](http://www.connectionstring.com)

by

Mohamed Inshafudeen J.

Answer (score 0):

For the error : Could not find installable ISAM.

1: save your excel file as "Excel 97-2003 wrokbook "
2: and also include the reference "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"

best of luck!